# Debugging a multi-threaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have inherited an application that throws up 100 threads at the start.  This makes my debugging life extremely tricky.  Is there a way of getting Visual Studio to follow one thread?

Comment: What version of VS are u using? VS 2008 / 2010 has facility where you can flag threads - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385628(v=VS.90).aspx - is that any help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried using the 'Threads' window in Visual Studio (in Debug / Windows menu) ?

You can freeze threads and switch between them

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I suggest that in Debug mode you limit the number of threads that are created, to a much more manageable number, e.g., 3. That way you can still can diagnose bugs due to interaction between threads, but you are not completely snowed under.

Answer (score 0):

Also the suggestion is in [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/8543248-make-the-debugger-stick-to-the-current-thread-inst) have just solved my problem.

```
if you hit a breakpoint, disable it, and then begin stepping you should not stop on a different thread
```

Comment: This is why we don't post link-only answers. If the link is broken now then please delete this answer. Don't edit it to say the link is broken.

Comment: I've already added the actual solution in there as you can see!