# How to Trace debug Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I made an application that works with httpwebrequests and also multihreads.

My issue is on larger projects it seems to halt the threads.

Is there any way i can trace where it halts if i run it in debug mode? Breakpoints wont work cause it may happen after a few hours.

One way i can think of it adding a logger to logg something into a textbox what it does all the time. But i want to learn more about Debugging in Visual Studio and hoping for there would be some kind of setting or similar to trace where the thread is in the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging a multi-threaded application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364738/debugging-a-multi-threaded-application)

Comment: You can instead of a Breakpoint use a Tracepoint. Just create your Breakpoint as usual, but then right click on it and click on `Actions...`. Now it logs whatever you want, whenever the code at that line gets executed.

Comment: Similar use a conditional breakpoint that stops when expression evaluates to true.

Comment: Hang dump analysis is much more a direct way to locate the cause. Just need to know the trick.